# Auto increment file name?

Tags: php, upload, increment

I want to make my Upload file website so when people upload file to to server i want server to increment the name of the file likes

- 1.png
- 2.png
- 3.png

So, How can i imcrement file name? And this is my code

```html
        <?php
 $limitsize = 1000000;
 $target_pics = "uploads/user/pics/" . basename($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]);
 $target_video = "uploads/user/video/" . basename($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]);
 $target_other = "uploads/user/other/" . basename($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]);
 $FileType = strtolower(pathinfo($target_video, PATHINFO_EXTENSION));
 $uploadOk = 1;


 // Check file exists

 if (file_exists($target_pics) || file_exists($target_video) || file_exists($target_other)) {
   echo "Sorry, file already exists. <br>";
   $uploadOk = 0
 }


 // Check file size

 if ($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["size"] > $limitsize) {
    echo "Sorry, your file is too large.";
    $uploadOk = 0;
 }


 if ($uploadOk == 0) {
    echo "Sorry, your file was not uploaded.";
 } else {
    if ($FileType == "jpg" || $FileType == "png" || $FileType == "jpeg" || $FileType == "gif" ) {
       move_uploaded_file($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"], $target_pics);
       echo "Upload Success.";
    } else {
       if ($FileType == "mp4" || $FileType == "avi") {
       move_uploaded_file($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"], $target_video);
       echo "Upload Success";
       } else {
           move_uploaded_file($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"], $target_other);
           echo "Upload Success";
         }
       }
     }
?>
```

Comment: So, what is the issue? What do currently get?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to what I understood, you need to store uploaded files on the server where files in the same directory have their names numbered. If so, you may use the below code that updates your posted code:

```
<?php
  $limitsize = 1000000;
  $target_pics = "uploads/user/pics/" . basename($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]);
  $target_video = "uploads/user/video/" . basename($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]);
  $target_other = "uploads/user/other/" . basename($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]);
  $FileType = strtolower(pathinfo($target_video, PATHINFO_EXTENSION));
  $uploadOk = 1;


  // Check file exists
  if (file_exists($target_pics) || file_exists($target_video) || file_exists($target_other)) {
   echo "Sorry, file already exists. <br>";
   $uploadOk = 0
 }


 // Check file size
 if ($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["size"] > $limitsize) {
    echo "Sorry, your file is too large.";
    $uploadOk = 0;
 }


 if ($uploadOk == 0) {
    echo "Sorry, your file was not uploaded.";
 } else {
    if ($FileType == "jpg" || $FileType == "png" || $FileType == "jpeg" || $FileType == "gif" ) {
       $num = count(scandir($target_pics)); // scandir: gets an array of the files in the directory
       move_uploaded_file($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"] . ($num + 1), $target_pics);
       echo "Upload Success.";
    } else {
       if ($FileType == "mp4" || $FileType == "avi") {
       $num = count(scandir($target_video));
       move_uploaded_file($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"] . ($num + 1), $target_video);
       echo "Upload Success";
       } else {
       $num = count(scandir($target_other));
           move_uploaded_file($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"] . ($num + 1), $target_other);
           echo "Upload Success";
         }
       }
     }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how to do this task in php but i am able to give you a solution using java 
in hibernate mapping inside the table mapping xml file there is tag call  its s a class with the help of this class you can do one thing id put inside the generator tag when you upload the file it will store with its actual name but with automatic generate id in ascending order and you can show as id.extension(like 2.png) enclose with  tag it is a linktext and when you want to download the file you just click on that respective id.extension linkText and remove the .extension from linkText use as a id and with help of id you got the data from database..
i hope it is useful to you.

Comment: As the OP is asking for a solution in PHP, this is probably not very useful as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Find the latest created file in uploaded folder and make new file rename with that file +1 name. Thats all...